# About definition of Fractional ideals: confusion (from Cohn's basic algebra)

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

> Let $\mathfrak{o}$ be an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions.
>
> By a fractional ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$ we mean an $\mathfrak{o}$-submodule
> $\mathfrak{A}$ of $K$ such that
> $$z\mathfrak{o} \subseteq \mathfrak{A} \subseteq u\mathfrak{o} \mbox{ for some } z,u\in K^{\times}. \hskip1cm (*)$$
> We note that (*) certainly holds when $0\neq \mathfrak{A}\subseteq \mathfrak{o}$.

I do not understnad the last line above. This is from P. M. Cohn's Basic algebra book.

If $0\neq \mathfrak{A}\subseteq \mathfrak{o}$ then take $u=1$ so that in (*) the second inequality holds; what about first?

This may be trivial, but I didn't get it; some books mention that $\mathfrak{A}$ is finitely generated $\mathfrak{o}$-submodule of $K$ in the definition of fractional ideal; but it was not the case in Cohn's book.

Comment: Since $0\neq\mathfrak{A}$ there exists an element $0\neq z=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathfrak{A}\backslash\{0\}\subset K^{\times}$ and since $\mathfrak{A}$ is a $\mathfrak{o}$-submodule of $K$ it follows $z\mathfrak{o}\subset\mathfrak{A}$?

Comment: Great! I didn't think in this simple way. Thanks for ir

Comment: You´re welcome!

Comment: Note: a non-zero finitely-generated $\mathfrak{o}$-submodule of $K$ is always a fractional ideal (just choose $u$ to be a common denominator of a generating system), but if $\mathfrak{o}$ is not Noetherian, then not every fractional ideal has to be finitely-generated: indeed, any non-zero ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$ that is also a fractional ideal, so if $\mathfrak{o}$ is not Noetherian, there's always a non f.g. frac. ideal. If $\mathfrak{o}$ is Noetherian, then submodules of f.g. modules are f.g. so any fractional ideal is f.g. as a submodule of the cyclic module $u\mathfrak{o}$.